# Making an indirect call in assembler

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I'm writing a compiler for a class, and I'm stuck on GNU's syntax for doing indirect call.  Consider this simple program:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
  movl func, %eax
  call *%eax
  ret

func:
  movl $42, %eax
  ret
```

Compiling with `gcc -m32 -O0` and running the resulting program gives me a segmentation fault.  Can anyone tell me how to do the call correctly?

Thanks.

Vincent.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897401/gnu-assembler-get-address-of-label-variable-intel-syntax

Answer (score 6):

The `call` instruction itself is actually good. :)

Your problem is that you seem to forget how the AT&T syntax works. What you're doing right here with `movl func, %eax` is copying a dword from the address of the label `func` to the `eax` register. Essentially, `eax` ends up with the first 4 bytes of actual code of your function.

Immediate operands in AT&T are prefixed with a `$`. The value of the `func` label, being a compile-time constant can be used as an immediate and that's what you want in this case. Therefore, replace `movl func, %eax` with `movl $func, %eax` and you'll be alright. :)

Using `lea` here is redundant. It will work, of course, but since `func` is a compile-time constant, it's much more effective to simply put it as an immediate in the code instead of figuring it out at runtime.

Answer (score -3):

I think I got it; using `lea`instead of `movl` fixed the problem; I imagine that lea does virtual address translation.

Comment: Nonsense. This has nothing to do with virtual addresses. `lea` loads the effective address of the label func into eax, while mov loads the content of the label at func, which are the opcodes of `mov $42, %eax` and do not make any sense if interpreted as address.